# tools to recreate a web application flow

Tags: web-applications

Are there any tools that can recreate web application flow..

for example i open www.abc.com and do some transactions in the application(basically i navigate between pages).....

So can i recreate the same transaction automatically using any tool .....

THanks in advance....

Answer (score 4):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) . You can record the session and replay it later.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Fiddler debugging tool to record your session as a WebTest. See [here](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/WebTest.asp).